# Java - All Elements in List Become Identical

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist

I'm having trouble using a for loop to assign elements to a List. Here's the section of code I'm having trouble with:

```
private static List<String[]> modify(List<String[]> data) {
    List<String[]> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
        String[] block = data.get(i);
        // some code here to modify the contents of block
        data2.add(block);
    }
    return data2;
}
```

For some reason, this method returns a List with all its elements completely identical. I've tried outputting the List elements to see where this is happening, and it seems to be happening outside of the loop. For example, this:

```
private static List<String[]> modify(List<String[]> data) {
    List<String[]> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
        String[] block = data.get(i);
        // some code here to modify the contents of block
        data2.add(block);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data2.get(i));
    }
    return data2;
}
```

displays a list of different elements, whereas this:

```
private static List<String[]> modify(List<String[]> data) {
    List<String[]> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
        String[] block = data.get(i);
        // some code here to modify the contents of block
        data2.add(block);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<data2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data2.get(i)));
    return data2;
}
```

displays a list consisting of only identical elements. It seems to me that the elements are being correctly added to the List inside of the for loop, yet end up becoming identical. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure it compiles ? 'List<String> data' and  'String[] block = data.get(i);' doesn't look correct.

Comment: I verified, this code does not compile.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake typing up the question. data is actually a List<String[]>.

Comment: Each element of `data2` references the same array as the corresponding element of `data`. So when you manipulate `block` you are actually modifying the contents of the array elements of each array stored in `data`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem! I had assumed that `data.get(i)` would return a copy of the array it referenced. Changing that to `data.get(i).clone()` fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make a temporary string to do the manipulations, initialize your String array, then fill it up with your data and then pass it to data2 like this:

```
private static List<String[]> modify(List<String> data) {
    List<String[]> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
        String tempString = data.get(i);
        String[] block = new String[255];
        // some code here to modify the contents of block
        // actually fill block with data
        block.add("modified data");
        block.add("more manipulated data");
        data2.add(block);
    }
    return data2;
}
```

**Edit**
This should fix the no compiling problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that you have managed to make this code run at all. There is an obvious syntax error in your code:

```
private static List<String[]> modify(List<String> data) {
...
  String[] block = data.get(i);
```

Your `block` is an array of `String`, whereas `data.get()` returns a single string. In the latter of your fragments the braces are unmatched, so it also should not get compiled. If you put '}' after `System.out.println(...);` and made the parameter of type `List<String>[]` instead of `List<String>`, your code would work fine.

Comment: And Klitos Kyriacou is right - you should remember that any modification of the `data` variable actually changes the items of the original list.

Comment: I think you might be right about adding '}' after println. As it is, it encounters the return statement inside the loop, which is not what was intended.

Comment: data is actually a `List<String[]>`. I'd mistyped it in my original question, but I've fixed it now.